# Is it possible to style the search suggestions in a searchbar? How does one call it through css?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a RoR website. I have a search bar wherein the user can input--however, the suggestions in the searchbar seem to come from recent searches based on internet history. Is there a way to style the search suggestions? I want the background of the search suggestions to be transparent. However I cannot seem to access the dropdown through css. Here's my HTML:

```
  <form action="/search">
   <input name="search_query" class="lanSearch" placeholder="" size="14" autofocus="autofocus"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="hide"/>
  </form>
```

Here's my css:

```
.lanSearch{
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 5vw;
    color:white;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:solid 3px white;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
```

Comment: What *provides* the functionality, and how is the 'suggestion' actually shown? I don't know of any browser that will populate suggestions from 'recent search history'..

Comment: i suggest you to create a jsfiddle

Comment: Are you talking about the suggestions of your browser? You cannot style them.

Comment: The suggestions are shown as a dropdown when I click the searchbar. I'm guessing they are browser suggestions?

Comment: searchbar = browser address bar or 'search widget' outside of the page?

Comment: Hi, the searchbar is an input field in my webpage.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/

Comment: I think it may be possible using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill although ```Note: The user agent style sheets of many browsers use !important in their :-webkit-autofill style declarations, making them non-overrideable by webpages without resorting to JavaScript hacks.```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style the internal autocomplete, but you can create an entirely custom search suggestions / autocomplete handling with the help of some CSS and JS and disable the internal one with:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off">
```