# Changing the width of the default drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, searchbar

Could someone tell me how I could change the width of the default drop-down menu that appears whenever I click on the search bar?
[Image of the drop-down menu on search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9k20.png)

**Update:** Thanks @bowlowl for letting me know that the default drop-down menu can not be edited.

Comment: You can't change the default browser dropdown, unfortunately. [See,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34306571/11789804)

Answer (score 0):

You can set width of dropdown by

```
.dropdown-menu {
 width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: .dropdown-menu is a built-in class? The width of the drop-down is still the same, it does not changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery onfocus event.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".searchbox" ).focus(function() {
      $('#dropdown').css('width','100%');
    });
    });
```

```html
 <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type to search" class="searchbox">
    <br>
    <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```